# How should incomplete freelance projects be presented in a CV?

Tags: resume, job-search, work-experience

I've got a freelance project that's technically finished but I'm waiting for the client to sort out domain registration, which could take up to a month. The deliverable website is available in a "lorem ipsum" state, not talking to the "real" DB but for all intents and purposes, functional.

I'm short in experience so I decided to put that in my CV without including the link, just the description. The headhunter told me the CV is incomplete because of it, and I should add (or send him) the URL so his client can see it.

- Should incomplete (or non-launched) projects be in the CV? If yes, how can I phrase it so I can highlight the situation?

Comment: Resumes are often full of projects that can't be made visible for some reason or another (e.g. internal, member-only, etc), so the recruiter's comment is odd given the context  you presented here.  How are you indicating your freelance work in the experience section of your resume -- a general description, a list of projects, something in-between? Is this the only project that doesn't have a URL associated with it?

Comment: @jcmeloni This is the only project, apart from a personal one on Github. The projects are presented as a list. I've made it clear that the website is meant to be public and given a list of features (eg. photo gallery, contact form, admin login etc.)

Comment: I've added the contact form because its inputs get encrypted before entering the DB, so I thought it would be interesting.

Comment: So you do _not_ have a corresponding entry in your experience section that is like "Freelance Developer, some dates", under which you list projects and briefly describe? You just present your projects as a list that doesn't correspond to an experience entry? I ask because if you frame yourself as a freelance developer & describe projects in general, you can get away from using the pure list that might look incomplete to someone (not me) w/o a URL.  I ask these clarifying questions to get at the underlying context to the question rather than "do I list or not list X".

Comment: @jcmeloni Ask away. The list contains two items, one marked "Personal" and the other "Freelance". I have other personal projects but none mature enough to include. The list currently contains the two items. I'm a fresh graduate and the work took place during the past year. I didn't include dates because of the small timescale.

Comment: Not exactly a dup (but close): My question is about projects that are _not yet_ ready for public consumption, the other is about projects that have been cancelled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your project is ready for deployment. That should be good enough for anyone who wants to check whether you can code at all, you can code cleanly and whether you coding style meshes with your prospective employer's people.

The definition of the word "complete" very much depends what the client defines as a deliverable.the client could define "gimme the code" as a deliverable, or the client states that you haven't a deliverable until the app is running fully deployed and with content provided on some Internet-facing host. Check the scope of work.

I suggest that you avoid and don't use the word "complete" because it's close to meaningless - it is obvious that the meaning of "complete" has a different meaning in the recruiter's mind than in either your mind's or that of the client's. I'll note that the recruiter doesn't get to define "complete" because the recruiter doesn't have a say about the scope of work.

Instead, say something like "the code is written, tested and ready for delivery to client" or "the code is written, tested, deployed on a host, further tested. The app is content provisioned and is about to go live on an Internet facing host. At which point, the client takes officially takes delivery of the work " depending on the scope of work.

Again, anyone who wants to review your ability to code has enough data at this point to draw their own conclusions. You are being hired on your  ability to deliver well-written, clean code and if you can provide tangible proof that you can write that kind of code, that proof should be good enough.

Comment: Very good points. I'll only remark that inspecting the code is difficult as it's been through compressors, but using "complete" is indeed a miscommunication waiting to happen. Cheers